# Jitsi Videobridge Negotiation

Tags: rest, webrtc, jitsi

I am trying to integrate [Jitsi Videobridge](https://jitsi.org/Projects/JitsiVideobridge) into my existing WebRTC application.

Right now the signaling is relatively straightforward, offer, answer, candidates and we're off and running.

I cannot find straightforward documentation or tutorials on how to integrate a selective forwarding solution like Jitsi, everything seems to speak at too high of a level (see [here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/firefox-multistream-and-renegotiation-for-jitsi-videobridge/)).

Can someone explain to me concretely how the offer, answer, candidate model changes with Jitsi and how can I can even get a 1-to-1 call established through the video bridge?

My current analysis leads me to believe that I'm supposed to hit [Jitsi over the REST interface](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-videobridge/blob/master/doc/rest-videobridge.md) to get candidates and swap out the `host`, `srvflx`, and `relay` candidates I generate currently with the ones from the video bridge. Is that even remotely on the right track?

Comment: What are you using for a signaling server?

Comment: Custom application server we've written that's Java. We use ActiveMQ (JMS, NMS, Stomp, etc.) to communicate with C#, Objective-C, Java, and Javascript endpoints. Right now we do 1-1 WebRTC through these inputs doing the standard peer to peer signaling via ActiveMQ.

Comment: You're asking a good question.  I want a description at the same level of abstraction, and independent of implementation language.  I have not found it yet.

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: I never got a great answer to this question. Eventually we started shifting resources into the Janus Gateway which we've had some success with.

Comment: Hello There, did you find any documentation for above question? Can you please answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549831/desktop-sharing-using-jitsi

Comment: Jitsi doesn't seem to be designed for easy integration with third party applications.  There are other SFUs that are, such as https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/,  https://github.com/pion/ion-sfu or https://galene.org (disclosure, I'm the main author of the latter).